# How to create watermark on each image while they are uploading with Uploadify? 

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I want to create a watermark using my own text for example. I want to create watermark of "ABDULLAH" on each image. I have these lines of code in my uploadify.php file.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/'; 
    $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['Filedata']['name']));
    $FileName = current(explode('.', $_FILES['Filedata']['name']));
    $originalFileName = $FileName.".".$ext;
    $strRandNum = rand(0,99)+strtotime(date('YmdHis'));
    $randomeFileName = $FileName."_".$strRandNum."_uid_".$_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $completeFileName = $randomeFileName.".".$ext;
    $dir_path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] .'/'. $dirctory_name. "/";
    if( (isset ($dirctory_name)) && ($dirctory_name != "") && (is_dir ($dir_path)) ) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$dir_path.$completeFileName);
    }
    else {
        mkdir($dir_path , 0777);
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$dir_path.$completeFileName);
    }
    str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
}
?>
```

Comment: i'm using uploadify plugin to upload multiple files..

Answer (score 1):

> well, you can't do it with javascript "uploadify" mr Abdullah
>
> you have to use the php gd lib to be able to put watermark

and that is done **AFTER** the image is uploaded not during upload

check this out

http://www.sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php/

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to need some form of server-side functionality.

CodeIgniter provides a built-in and easy way of adding watermarks to images during the file upload process.  Check out their documentation for [uploading files](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) and [image manipulation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html).